# SQL Aggregate Count statement

Tags: sql

I'm on the last "advanced select statement" question and cant quite seem to get the correct answer.

Table 1: Schema for the bookworm database. Primary keys are underlined. There are some foreign key references to link the tables together; you can make use of these with natural joins.

```
Author(aid, alastname, afirstname, acountry, aborn, adied).
Book(bid, btitle, pid, bdate, bpages, bprice).
City(cid, cname, cstate, ccountry).
Publisher(pid, pname).
Author_Book(aid, bid).
Publisher_City(pid, cid).
```

The question is ... "Find the names of authors who have written three or more books."

The code works but I want the full author name instead of the author id..

```
select count(aid) as authorBook, aid as authorName
from Author_book natural join Author
group by aid
having count(aid) > 3;
```

The final table comes up as...

```
 authorbook | authorname 
------------+------------
      8 | dick
      4 | thar
(2 rows)
```

Comment: You need both author and book tables in your query. JOIN or sub-select!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `HAVING COUNT(aid) > 3` you cannot use the alias authorBook.

Well if you need the author's name and its in the table you can do this:

`SELECT AuthorName, COUNT(*) AS CountOfBooks
FROM AuthorBooks GROUP BY AuthorName HAVING COUNT(*) > 3`

If the author's name is a foreign key do this:

```
SELECT x.AuthorName, COUNT(x2.*) FROM
AuthorBooks x2 INNER JOIN Authors x1 ON x1.AuthorID = x2.AuthorID
GROUP BY x.AuthorName HAVING COUNT(x2.*) > 3
```

Comment: I'm trying to associate the authors names as well.

Comment: @ZekeP, Thats why you need authors table in your query. Try join, or sub-select!

Comment: You're leading me in the right direction but instead of using "AuthorName" I have to use "aid" since AuthorName does not exist. Im trying to incorporate the full name of the author not just the authorID. I tried adding "afistname, alastname natural join Author" before the "count(aid) as authorBook" but get an error....

Comment: Zeke use your column names, mine is just an example of how to do it, you need to change it to match your column names / table names / business rules etc.

Comment: I think I need both the Author and Author_book tables but cant get it to go through using natural join...

Comment: I edited the question. I have a solution but just want to make it more easier to know the exact author name

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  A.alastname,
        A.afirstname,
        COUNT(*) as Books
FROM Author_Book AB
INNER JOIN Author A
    ON AB.aid = A.aid
GROUP BY aid
HAVING COUNT(*) > 3
```